# Woocommerce discount - percentage only in whole numbers sent to distribution - how to calculate without losses for the customer or company

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, discount

I am trying to figure out how to control the discount behavior of my website so it collaborates with an external distribution channel. Right now i have a successful mail send with a XML-file attached when the customer has finished paying.

The only data field that is causing trouble is the discount. Because:

**The disctribution channel only accepts discount for each item (product) as percentage that is a whole number**

*I've used simpleXML and added data for each item (sold product) like this - only a section of the full code*

```
// Basic $order data and wp_mail configurations BEFORE
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {

      $product = $item->get_product();
      $isbn = get_field( 'isbn', $item->get_product_id() );
      $price = $product->get_price(); 
      $quantity = $item->get_quantity();

      $order_line = $order_head->addChild( 'Ordrelinje' );
      $order_line->addAttribute( 'besked', 'notat tilknyttet ordrelinjen' );
      $order_line->addAttribute( 'rabatprocent', '' ); 
      $order_line->addAttribute( 'stykpris', $price );
      $order_line->addAttribute( 'antal', $quantity );
      $order_line->addAttribute( 'isbn', $isbn );

    } 
// SimpleXML save and attachment created with the XML file AFTER
// Sent with wp_mail and the return tested AFTER
```

So the problem is basically:

I know how to calculate the percentage from full price and discount in the product[] data, but i have difficulties imagine a flexible system with different discount-possibilities (see bottom)

With both percentage- and amount discount you could imagine having a conflict with whole based number when calculating the percentage after purchase. Some decimals would be lost.

#### Example:

Let's say that i make a discount on one book at 22 KR (danish) and the price without discount were: 143.

Then the discount in percentage would be: 100/143*22: 15.38%.

I would then for example, to get a whole number as percentage, round with `round(15.38, 0)` to get 15.

And then the customer would lose: `.38%` that is `143*0.0038 = 0.54KR`

---

So my question is:

**Does anyone has an idea how to get solve this, or a workaround so the amount discount is a whole number of the regular price in percentage for example. Or have other ideas?**

Comment: No matter how you slice this. Someone is going to lose something.

Comment: I read it again - and i see what you mean. It cannot be solved.. of course - i was almost about to say.